# Google apps script permission to access a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-apps

This simple code works in a standalone script and also in a script bound to a google sheet if i run directly the function, but get a permission error when i run it opening the sheet. Where is the problem?

```
function onOpen() {
  jsondir = DriveApp.getFolderById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
  Logger.log(jsondir)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of use of method (DriveApp) which is required the authorization, the function has to be installed as a trigger. How to install the trigger is as follows. The detail information is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

- On the script editor.

  - Edit -> Current project's triggers
  - Click "No triggers set up. Click here to add one now."
  - At "Run", select "onOpen"
  - At Events, select "From spreadsheet" and "On open"
  - Push "Save" button.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.